# Size of Integer objects in JAVA

Tags: java

This is the elaboration of the memory of an object of the below class that stores N items of type Integer.
What I do not fully understand is where the memory for Integer Objects comes from. Isn't that already taken care of? And if so why is it 24 bytes?

I mean 24N for Integer objects.

```
public class GenericMysteryBox<Item> 
{        //       16 (object overhead)
 private int N;                            //        4 (int)
 private Item[] items;                     //        8 (reference to array)
                                          //  8N + 24 (array of Integer references)
                                          //      24N (Integer objects)
...                                                 4 (padding to round up to a multiple of 8)
}
```

Comment: No. You need memory for the _reference_ **and** for the `Object`. As for the second part, what's `24 - 16` and what's significant about `16`?